# perl6 spurt vs file handle

Tags: raku, spurt

It seems that every time I call `spurt` without `:append`, it will open and overwrite the file and then close the file automatically. I have been writing thousands of lines to a file in a routine using spurt. Now it seems like a big waste of I/O resources. I guess if I need to write thousands of lines, I should always use "open" to get a file handle instead. Comments?

Comment: Yes use [`open`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/open) instead.

Comment: I'm confused. You write that "open ... overwrite ... close ... seems like a big waste of I/O resources." Why? Also, "I guess if I need to write thousands of lines, I should always use "open" to get a file handle instead [of `spurt`]." and @HåkonHægland responds with an upvoted "yes". Again, why? Presumably the same confusion is leading me to both of my "Why?"s and there's just one key thing I'm missing. But I've reread your question a couple times, reread the doc, and I'm still not getting what problem you're seeing let alone how using `open` instead of `spurt` fixes it. TIA for deconfusion.

Comment: In the beginning we had 'open...read/write...close'. A frequent use case was reading the whole file, so `slurp` was invented.  Writing the whole file at once was useful as well, so `spurt` was added.  You can always use the original routines if you don't have the simple use cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use `open` to get a file handle, and use `print` or `say` (or `write` for binary data) to append to it.

`spurt` is only useful for one-off operations, and meant to relieve you having to write `open`, `print` and `close` for a single logical write operation.

Comment: Thank you moritz, Hakon Haegland, raiph, and Curt Tilmes for clearing up my question. raiph, I wasn't careful enough in using "open" vs "spurt". Now I understand: with open, the process is: open file, (write a line) xx 1000, close file; with spurt, it is: (open file, write a line, close file) xx 1000. With spurt, there are 1000 open and 1000 close operations. Thanks !!!